# Скрытие картинки спустя 2 секунды без действия мыши

Tags: javascript, dom

Есть код, который при движение мыши добавляет картинку(кошку) с мышке и двигается за ней:

Вешаю на движение мыши обработчик. Добавляю картинку.

```
document.onmousemove = function() {

    document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].insertAdjacentHTML('beforeEnd', '<img src ="cat.png" id="cat" >');
```

Далее получаю картинку cat.

```
var cat = document.getElementById('cat');
```

Перехватываю событие мышью. Перемещаю картинку по осям за мышью

```
var move = document.onmousemove = function(event) {
        clearTimeout(timer)

        cat.style.position = 'fixed';
        cat.style.left = event.clientX + 20 + 'px';
        cat.style.top = event.clientY + 20 + 'px';
        var timer = setTimeout(() => cat.style.display= 'none', 2000);
    }
```

Надо чтобы картинка скрывалась после простоя мыши более чем две секунды.Пробовал через setTimeout, но не получается. Подскажите пж.

Answer (score 5):

Вставьте картинку в html с самого начала - не javascript-ом.
И вынесите объявление переменной `timer` из функции

```js
var cat = document.getElementById('cat');
var timer;
document.onmousemove = function(event) {
  clearTimeout(timer);

  cat.style.display = 'block';
  cat.style.position = 'fixed';
  cat.style.left = event.clientX + 20 + 'px';
  cat.style.top = event.clientY + 20 + 'px';

  timer = setTimeout(() => cat.style.display = 'none', 2000);
}
```

```html
<img src="https://i.i.ua/avatar/mini/0/1/3411110_208340730.jpg" id="cat" style="display:none;" />
```

Comment: Блин, чувак, спасибо тебе я два дня тужился.